# Is prefetching mysql records at the beginning faster than fetching the same data during a call?

Tags: php, mysql, benchmarking

I have this doubt: I have a php that retrieves results from a mysql table. In terms of optimization, would it be wiser to retrieve the data at the beginning of the php script so that I can use it below? Or is it exactly the same as retrieving the data when the information is going to be printed?

Comment: there is still no code, i needed to clear that doubt before writing the code ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need to process the results, just display them, there no advantage to the one or the other.

Answer (score 1):

If your script needs heavy processing then it might be wise to open the database connection right before fetching the data and close the connection right after. The shorter a connection stays open, the faster new requests can be handled.

Comment: IMO it's better to keep shared connections open via singleton throughout script lifetime, vs having to open/close a connection every query. Otherwise if you are explicitly closing connections throughout the code then re-opening you may end up with the ever feared 'too many connections open' error.

Comment: Indeed, you should only open 1 connection if possible. What I meant was that you should open the connection right before the first query and close it right after the last one. Keep connection open as short as possible.

Comment: The problem is, how will you know when the first query and last query occur? If you support a complex application, this would be difficult to discern. I would recommend adding some logic to a __destruct() function to the database class where your singleton's reside, and null them to close them. So when the script processsing end of life has been reached, they close automatically.